# What is the most efficient way to add elements into a list in Java?

Tags: java, performance, list, memory-efficient

Today at work I had a discussion with 2 developers regarding the way to add an element into a list. They told me that this is the more efficient way:

```
final FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo();
for (GroupInfo groupInfo : cft.getGroupFiles()) {
    fileInfo.setClassName(groupInfo.getClassGeneration());
    fileInfo.setFileId(groupInfo.getId().getCfgFileTypeId());
    fileInfoList.add(fileInfo);
}
```

But I'd always done it in a slightly different way:

```
for (GroupInfo groupInfo : cft.getGroupFiles()) {
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo();
    fileInfo.setClassName(groupInfo.getClassGeneration());
    fileInfo.setFileId(groupInfo.getId().getCfgFileTypeId());
    fileInfoList.add(fileInfo);
}
```

So, what is the most efficient way to do this? Why? I think that the first way uses less memory than the second way, but the second way generates a new instance and for an instance, a new memory-reference and then adds it to the list, but I had bad experiences using the first way when I had to convert or use some elements from the list using the first way...So, can you help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: the first 'method' will end up with a list filled with the same `FileInfo` object with the properties of the last `GroupInfo` -- I doubt that is intended

Comment: first way, is not actually at all a way :) , At the end of loop you will end up having same object throughout the list with the last values of loop.

Comment: You're coworkers prefer broken code just for the imagine, that this might be faster? This isn't even important, since JIT would take care about optimization here.

Comment: I hope that isn't what they really told you, otherwise you need two new co-workers. More likely they told you to declare the variable outside the loop and assign it inside. But if they think that's faster, they're dreaming.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you're mutating then adding the **same** instance of `FileInfo`. Thus you'll end up with `fileInfoList` referencing the same instance of `FileInfo`, which will have the state of the last loop iteration. I'm pretty sure this is not the desired behavior. As usual, correctness supersedes efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Below list will only have one element:

```
final FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo();
for (GroupInfo groupInfo : cft.getGroupFiles()){
    fileInfo.setClassName(groupInfo.getClassGeneration());
    fileInfo.setFileId(groupInfo.getId().getCfgFileTypeId());
    fileInfoList.add(fileInfo);
}
```

And below will have as many are in `cft.getGroupFiles()` list.

```
final FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo();
for (GroupInfo groupInfo : cft.getGroupFiles()){
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo();
    fileInfo.setClassName(groupInfo.getClassGeneration());
    fileInfo.setFileId(groupInfo.getId().getCfgFileTypeId());
    fileInfoList.add(fileInfo);
}
```

So we can't compare both methods on the basis of memory efficiency as each one is a different implementation.

Comment: This answer is redundant after reading the comments. Perhaps we should wait for clarification from OP. Maybe they missed some code.